# When User selecting Dropdown

Tags: c#, winforms, sql-server-2008

this is event of dropdown when a value select from dropdown it will run(Input string was not in a correct format. ERROR always COMES Plz Help ME Now)

```
private void cmbRoom_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cmbRoom.SelectedValue.ToString() != "")
    {
        int RoomSelectedID = Convert.ToInt32(cmbRoom.SelectedValue.ToString());
        BindDataRoomBeed(RoomSelectedID);
        cmbBed.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: int RoomSelectedID = Convert.ToInt32(cmbRoom.SelectedValue.ToString()); Error Coming Here

Comment: What is the value off cmbRoom.SelectedValue.ToString() as in recond it isn't an integer

Comment: Better check is: `!String.IsnullOrEmpty(cmbRoom.SelectedValue)`

Answer (score 0):

```
private void cmbRoom_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cmbRoom.SelectedValue.ToString()))
    {
        int RoomSelectedID = Convert.ToInt32(cmbRoom.SelectedValue.ToString());
        BindDataRoomBeed(RoomSelectedID);
        cmbBed.SelectedIndex = 0;
    }
}
```

Hope your value is integer only..

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of collection items binded to your control?

This type overrides ToString method?

Does overloaded ToString method of this type returns you number?

I think the reason is in not overloaded ToString method of collection item type.

Answer (score 0):

```
// try this

 int RoomSelectedID = Convert.ToInt32(cmbRoom.SelectedText.ToString());
```